# axios-cache-interceptor "setupCache() should be called only once" error with next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

I'm trying to use axios-cache-interceptor to cache requests. However, when I try to set it up I get this error: `Error: setupCache() should be called only once`

```
   7 | import { setupCache } from "axios-cache-interceptor";
   8 | 
>  9 | const axios = setupCache(Axios)
     |                       ^
  10 | 
  11 | export default function DashboardPage() {
  12 | const { data: session } = useSession();
```

I tried putting the axios object in a seperate file, setting up the cache there and then export the set up cache axios object so that it'd only run once, but it did nothing different.

Answer (score 1):

Maintainer of axios-cache-interceptor here!

Probably you are executing the line 9 multiple times which throws this error. You can avoid by checking if the interceptor was already applied:

```
import type { AxiosCacheInstance } from 'axios-cache-interceptor';

// Axios.defaults.cache will be defined if the interceptor was already
// applied before
const instance = Axios.defaults.cache ? Axios as AxiosCacheInstance : setupCache(Axios);
```

https://github.com/arthurfiorette/axios-cache-interceptor/issues/718#issuecomment-1806892329

Comment: this is not typesafe.

Comment: I get this error: Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'Omit<AxiosDefaults<any>, "headers"> & { headers: HeadersDefaults & { [key: string]: AxiosHeaderValue; }; }'.ts(2339)

Comment: I have updated the original reply with correct type information and a link to the proper GitHub issue, thanks!